# Android won't start. It keeps showing Samsung Galaxy logo

Tags: recovery-mode, boot

It keeps showing the logo and doesn't get into Android. What do you recommend me to do?

I've tried hard reset, it didn't work.

[image: Even though I wait 1 hour, it is the same]
<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: What did you do before this happened? Did you flash a new ROM?

Comment: I gave it to my kid to play a game. After a few hours, I found it as turned off. I thought that battery was empty and tried to charge and turn it on. No chance

Comment: Does your kid know what happened to the phone? Maybe the reason for your problem might be something he has done by mistake or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed 4.1.2 Jelly Bean XXEMD2 Firmware from the scratch. It's working now
Instructions: http://port135.com/2013/06/30/708/